# Meaning of かかった毛並み in this sentence

Tags: meaning

I've come across a sentence describing a nekomata that I only partially understand. Here it is:

**全身白色の体毛に薄い桃色がかかった毛並みをしている.**

I understand that it's talking about the nekomata's fur color, which is white with light pink, but I'm unsure of the second part of the sentence.

What does かかった毛並み mean here? I've split it up into two parts (かかった and 毛並み) but I'm still unsure as to what it means.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You sure it's 桃色が**か**かった, not 桃色**がかった** ? (桃色がかかった would also make sense but I want to make sure.)

Comment: 接尾辞「がかった」を含む（複合修飾語っぽい性質の）「薄い桃色がかった」より、動詞の「かかった」を含む(「主語+動詞」の構造を持つ)「薄い桃色がかかった」の方が、関係節中の動作・作用の行われる対象（場所？）を示す格助詞句「全身白色の体毛に」の適切性が明確な気がしますね。

Comment: @Chocolate Yeah, what I have is what is written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

かかる can mean:

> かかる
>   ㊸ そのような性質・傾向を帯びる。
>   「青みの**かかった**緑色」
>   (from 明鏡国語辞典)

「青みの**かかった**緑色」 = "blu**ish** green" (≂ 青みを[帯]{お}びた緑色)

---

It can also be used in the form of がかる as a suffix:

> かかる
>   ㈢ 〘接尾〙《名詞に付いて、「がかる」の形で》
>   ❷ ‥‥色を帯びる意を表す。
>   「紫［黄色・黒み・オレンジ］**がかった**赤い色」
>   (from 明鏡国語辞典)

An example from プログレッシブ和英辞典:

> 紫**がかった**灰色の上着 a purpl**ish** gray coat

Comment: I tried to answer this question but it was a bit beyond my knowledge, but I thought the person was asking what the difference was between the 体毛 and the 毛並み parts of the cat fur.

Comment: ^ およよ・・・体毛は body hair って感じで、毛並みは fur, coat って感じですかね・・